# Передать имя класса в функцию, которая создаст объект этого класса

Tags: python

В Python нужно написать функцию, которая получает 'class_name' и создает объект этого класса

```
class A(object):
    pass


class B(object):
    pass


def return_obj(class_name):                          # Если class_name = "A" функция выполняет obj = A()
    obj = 'Здесь конструкция для создания объекта'   # Если class_name = "B" функция выполняет obj = B() 
    return obj
```

Comment: Нужно именно строку, почему не передать сам класс?

Answer (score 3):

```
def return_obj(class_name):
    return globals()[class_name]()
```